# Call AsyncTask in a Fragment (FragmentStatePagerAdapter issue)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I know this question has already been asked, but I can't find any solution to it. 

Here is the thing : 
- I have an `Activity` which host three tabs. 
- Each tab is a `Fragment`. 
- The whole thing is managed using a `FragmentSatePagerAdapter` 

When I slide to the last tab, I would like to send a request to the server and populate a `ListView` with the `Json` received. Sounds pretty easy. 
I have a class which extends AsyncTask and I use it to process the request to the server

```
public class HttpAsyncNotif extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray>{
    private TabOperations tabOperationsCaller; // This is my fragment

    public HttpAsyncNotif(TabOperations caller){
        this.tabOperationsCaller = caller;
    }

    // Others methods of Asynctask
}
```

And this is the code of my Fragment (which is the last tabs)

```
public class TabOperations extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_operations, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser){
           new HttpAsyncNotif(this).execute(user.getUsername()); // Got the NullPointerException
        }
    }
}
```

I looked in details at the Life Cycle of a Fragment, but I still have no solutions.

How can I do this?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: where you initialized that user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 new HttpAsyncNotif(this).execute(user.getUsername());
```

to

```
 new HttpAsyncNotif(getActivity()).execute(user.getUsername());
```

get `Context` in `Fragment` by using `getActivity()`

also check `user!=null` before `user.getUsername()`

Comment: If I do this, how can I change the constructor of `HttpAsynNotif` to pass a link to the `TabOperation` Fragment? (because this is where I need to send back the Json received)

Comment: @Mornor Pass link as a Second Argument in your  `HttpAsynNotif` constructor

Comment: Many thanks! Took a some time to test it .. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `Context` you have passed .Change the code into

```
 new HttpAsyncNotif(getActivity()).execute(user.getUsername());
```